# Using meta tags for Facebook in a SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, master-page, metadata

I have a public-facing SharePoint Foundation 2013 site, http://www.oceanview335.com. It is NOT a SharePoint Online site. I am trying to build meta tags in the master page so I can control the data shown when posting to Facebook. I have it working except for the image, which for me is the most important part.

Here are my meta tags in the master page:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.oceanview335.com/SitePages/Home.aspx" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Ocean View Lodge No. 335" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Ocean View Lodge No. 335" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.oceanview335.com/Pictures/OV_eye_small.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Ocean View Masonic Lodge No. 335
A. F. & A. M. Norfolk, Virginia" />
```

Based on suggestions I found in stackoverflow and elsewhere, I added this line:

```
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg"
href="http://www.oceanview335.com/Pictures/OV_eye_small.jpg" />
```

Using the Object Debugger for Facebook, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug I get the following results:

```
og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough.
Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's
at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook.
Image 'http://www.oceanview335.com/Pictures/2015%20DDGMs.png' will be used instead.
```

The end result is, if I create a NEW post in Facebook, the image from my home page "2015%20DDGMs.png" is displayed. If I COMMENT on an existing post, the correct image "OV_eye_small.jpg" is displayed. I have tried various suggestions, such as resizing the image to 200x200 or a multiplication thereof. The current image is 200x200. I have tried .png and .jpg images. I have added the image_src link listed above. Nothing I found through Googling to try has removed this "image was not defined" error or given me the correct image in Facebook posts.

UPDATE: I just posted this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567114/using-meta-tags-for-facebook-in-a-sharepoint-site) as I have received zero responses. I think this problem is specific to SharePoint sites. Using Twitter Cards, which also use meta tags, work flawlessly: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started​

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I struggled with the same issue.  The way we solved it:

This type was "website".  The [FB documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) recommends images be 600X315 for this type.  We use a 600X315 jpg, and defined the additional specs of the image in these tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="[Your URL to image here]" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="600" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="315" />
```

This seemed to help FB digest the image.  If you change the image, I suggest renaming it, as in our experience FB caches the old image, and it takes forever to grab the new one.